# How to create dynamic collection view in a table view cell, without reloading table view swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this code in cellForRowAt :

```
cell.frame = tableView.bounds
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    collectionView.reloadData()
    heightConstraint.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

This works at the first time, but when I load more items to collection view it doesn't work unless I use `tableView.reloadData()`

But when I use `tableView.reloadData()` scrolling stops for a second, and I want it to flow without freezing.

Anyone has a solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reload only the cell that you are updating in case you don't want to reload the table

```
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath], with: .none)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you change a cell height *after* it has been displayed, you need to tell the table view about it.

You haven't shown how or when you *"load more items to collection view"* ... but after you do that, call:

```
tableView.performBatchUpdates(nil, completion: nil)
```

That will cause the table view to recalculate and update the row heights, without calling `.reloadData()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to do pagination, I load more items when user reaches the bottom of the table view.

Comment: If adding that line doesn't solve your issue, you need to edit your question and include the code you are using. We can't guess at what you're doing.